# get list from DB and merge the common fields of the list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list as follows:-

```
List<ScheduleActionDispatchDTO> pendingScheduleActions 
=restClientApi.getPendingSchedules();
```

The above list is coming from DB whose values are like this -

```
schedule_request_id = 576, user_id = 24, 
start_time_utc = '2022-12-16 21:00:00', end_time_utc = '2022-12-17 01:00:00', 
request_json = '{"testId": "5", "grade": "A"}'

schedule_request_id = 576, user_id = 24, 
start_time_utc = '2022-12-16 21:00:00', end_time_utc = '2022-12-17 01:00:00', 
request_json = '{"subjectId": "10", "name": "dictation"}'

schedule_request_id = 577, user_id = 24, start_time_utc = '2022-12-17 21:00:00', 
end_time_utc = '2022-12-18 01:00:00', request_json = '{"testId": "5", "grade": "A"}'
```

Now I want the result to be such that if values of `schedule_request_id`, `user_id`, `start_time_utc` and `end_time_utc` of any rows are same then merge the values of `request_json` of those rows together.

So it should become -

```
schedule_request_id = 576, user_id = 24, 
start_time_utc = '2022-12-16 21:00:00', end_time_utc = '2022-12-17 01:00:00', 
combinedResult = '[{"testId": "5", "grade": "A"}, {"subjectId": "10", "name": "dictation"}]'
```

and

```
schedule_request_id = 577, user_id = 24, start_time_utc = '2022-12-17 21:00:00', 
end_time_utc = '2022-12-18 01:00:00', combinedResult = '{"testId": "5", "grade": "A"}'
```

I tried this -

```
Map<Long, List<ScheduleActionDispatchDTO>> requestMap = pendingScheduleActions.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                            ScheduleActionDispatchDTO::getScheduleRequestId, Collectors.toList()));

for (Map.Entry<Long, List<ScheduleActionDispatchDTO>> entry : requestMap.entrySet()) {
   List<ScheduleActionDispatchDTO> sameRequestActions = entry.getValue();
   Map<ScheduleActionDispatchPair, ScheduleActionDispatchDTO> schedulePairAction =
                            sameRequestActions.stream().
                            collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            s -> new ScheduleActionDispatchPair(s.getScheduleRequestId(), s.getUserUd(), s.getStartTimeUtc(), s.getEndTimeUtc()),
                            s -> s));

// iterate and combine but not sure how

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do the following. I assumed you have a record<sup>1</sup> of the following form:

```java
public record PendingScheduleAction(
    long scheduleRequestId,
    int userId,
    LocalDateTime startTimeUtc,
    LocalDateTime endTimeUtc,
    String requestJson
) { }
```

We could first create a `Merger`, which is used as grouping-by key. We add an `ofPendingScheduleAction` method, which is a convenience method to ease the grouping-by. We also add a `merge` method, which is able to merge two `PendingScheduleAction` objects.

```java
record Merger(long scheduleRequestId, int userId, LocalDateTime startTimeUtc, LocalDateTime endTimeUtc) {

    public static Merger ofPendingScheduleAction(PendingScheduleAction action) {
        return new Merger(action.scheduleRequestId(), action.userId(), action.startTimeUtc(), action.endTimeUtc());
    }

    private static PendingScheduleAction merge(PendingScheduleAction a, PendingScheduleAction b) {
        String json = a.requestJson() + '\0' + b.requestJson();
        return new PendingScheduleAction(a.scheduleRequestId(), a.userId(), a.startTimeUtc(), a.endTimeUtc(), json);
    }
}
```

Now you can utilize `groupingBy`, `reducing` and `collectingAndThen` in order to achieve the desired result:

```java
list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Merger::ofPendingScheduleAction, collectingAndThen(reducing(Merger::merge), optional -> {
        var entry = optional.orElseThrow();
        String[] jsonLines = entry.requestJson().split("\0");
        String json = (jsonLines.length == 1 ? jsonLines[0] : "[" + String.join(",", jsonLines) + "]");
        return new PendingScheduleAction(entry.scheduleRequestId(), entry.userId(), entry.startTimeUtc(), entry.endTimeUtc(), json);
    })));
```

What happens here, is that we first define how our `PendingScheduleAction` instances are grouped. The Javadocs call this the *classifier*. Now you said *"such that if values of `schedule_request_id`, `user_id`, `start_time_utc` and `end_time_utc` of any rows are same then merge"*, so we need to have those properties together into an object. The `Merger` class does this.

Then `Collectors.reducing(Merger::merge)` takes all objects of a group and merges them using the `Merger::merge` method. Since `reducing` returns an `Optional`, we need to unpack it (with `orElseThrow`), but we also need to fix the JSON, since we temporarily joined it with a `NUL` byte.

Then the result is a `Map<Merger, PendingScheduleAction>`, of which you can call `values()` to get a list with the merged values.

---

A few notes:

- I used a `NUL` byte to temporarily separate different JSON parts (which is kinda hacky). This is due to your requirement that you want multiple merged JSON entries to be in a JSON array, but a single entry without an array. I suggest you put *all* JSON entries into an array, regardless of the number of entries (which may be 1). This is both easier to parse and easier to process.

  You could replace all `\0`s by `,` in the abovementioned code and the *finisher function* of the `collectingAndThen` method would look like this:

  ```java
  var entry = optional.orElseThrow();
  return new PendingScheduleAction(entry.scheduleRequestId(), entry.userId(), entry.startTimeUtc(), entry.endTimeUtc(), "[" + entry.requestJson() + "]");
  ```
- Your start time and end time suggest they are UTC timestamps, but the date strings show a local time. I think your timestamps should look like something like this: `2022-12-16T21:00:00Z`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> If you don't have access to the *records* feature, you could easily simulate them with the following:</sup>

```java
public class PendingScheduleAction {
    private long scheduleRequestId;
    private int userId;
    private LocalDateTime startTimeUtc;
    private LocalDateTime endTimeUtc;
    private String requestJson;

    // Canonical all-args constructor
    public PendingScheduleAction(long scheduleRequestId, int userId, LocalDateTime startTimeUtc, LocalDateTime endTimeUtc, String requestJson) {
        this.scheduleRequestId = scheduleRequestId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.startTimeUtc = startTimeUtc;
        this.endTimeUtc = endTimeUtc;
        this.requestJson = requestJson;
    }

    // Record-style getter (just the name of the field, not starting with 'get'
    public long scheduleRequestId() {
        return scheduleRequestId;
    }

    // And the remaining getters

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // A proper equals implementation.
        // Don't forget hashCode()
    }
}
```

<sub>You could also use Lombok to annotate the class with `@AllArgsConstructor`, `@Getter` and `@EqualsAndHashCode`.</sub>

Comment: I am using java8 and there is no record class available in that version. Also the above will merge the two PendingScheduleAction objects.. but what if the objects are more then two.

Comment: @MyGod Well, a `record` is easily converted to a normal class – it's just a little more typing. I will update the answer to include this. And regarding multiple `PendingScheduleAction` objects – well, `reducing` does not simply merge *two* objects, but each next element in the pipeline is merged with the previous one.

Comment: How can I use Merger  now as I am not using record now ? It is giving compile time error. Can you update?

Comment: @MyGod It doesn't really matter whether you use a record or a regular class. If you got a compiler error, then please share your attempt (e.g. via an Ideone link or as edit to your question).